# Como posso fazer para receber todos os valores que correspondem a uma lista de busca

Tags: javascript

Olá,

Tenho a seguinte lista de objetos:

```
0:
id: 1
firstName: Pedro
lastName: Silva
code: AA
1:
id: 2
firstName: Maria
lastName: Lurdes
code: AB
2:
id: 3
firstName: Joao
lastName: Silva
code: BA
```

Após preencher uma lista com os IDs que pretendo recuperar

```
match = [1,3]
```

Como posso fazer para recuperar num novo objeto os objetos com IDs "1" e "2"?

De momento tenho o seguinte código:

```
let match = totalObjs.filter((current) => current.id == matches);
```

Neste momento se procurar só por um ID funciona mas não é o que preciso...
O objetivo pretendido é o seguinte:

```
0:
id: 1
firstName: Pedro
lastName: Silva
code: AA
2:
id: 3
firstName: Joao
lastName: Silva
code: BA
```

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode trocar a comparação por uma verificação se o índice do id no array é diferente de `-1` (que é o retorno no caso de não existir):

```js
console.log([1,2,3].indexOf(1) != -1)
console.log([2,3].indexOf(1) != -1)
```

Há outras funções de filtro que podem ser usadas, mas essa é a forma mais simples

Answer (score 0):

Olá eu usaria assim.

```
let result = [
  {
    id: 1,
    firstName: 'Pedro',
    lastName: 'Silva',
    code: 'AA',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    firstName: 'Maria',
    lastName: 'Lurdes',
    code: 'AB',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    firstName: 'Joao',
    lastName: 'Silva',
    code: 'BA',
  }
]

let myBusca = function(list, propert){
  let listFilter = [];
  listFilter.push(result.map(current => {
    if(list.indexOf(current[propert]) !== -1){
      return current;
    }
  }))
  return listFilter;
}
console.log(myBusca([1, 3], 'id'));
console.log(myBusca(['AA', 'BA'], 'code'));
```